# VirtualBox and Websockets

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, forwarding, sockets

I am using Virtualbox with Linux host and Windows guest.

When I try to use websites that makes use of websockets it's not working properly (not getting messages). I believe this can be fixed with Virtualbox network configuration but I have no idea how to do that.

When I run a test in http://www.websocket.org/echo.html it works on host but not guest OS, so it's not an ISP issue.

Comment: What kind of network configuration are you using for the guest?

Comment: Tried NAT and Bridged with same results

Comment: What about the Windows firewall?. Or running Wireshark on the guest to verify if the connection is not reaching it? Note: the "new" NAT option in VB I find it very unstable. I would test the old NAT and forward the corresponding ports with the host.

Comment: I tried disabling Windows firewall, didn't help. I'm using "NAT" and not "NAT Network" now. If I choose "NAT Network" it doesn't let me choose network name because there are no such networks, I guess I should try to create one manually in host? Will try Wireshark a little later.